# size edges and vertex of adjancency list c++

Tags: c++, graph

I have a graph and it is adjancent list V (vertex) and E(edges). is there any way get number of edges and vertex dividing bit's size like arrays sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[]).

Briefly: I want to find sum of each vector size without looping.

Note:I didn t try below code is working.

```
Graph::Graph(unordered_map<unsigned int,vector<pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>>> data)
    {
        V = data.size();
        for ( auto i : data )
        {
            E = E + i.second.size();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `i.second.size()` returns the length of a `vector<pair<unsigned,unsigned>>`. Is that really what you want? It's not clear what you're trying to find.

Comment: ı want to find sum of each vector lenght but not using "for loop".

Comment: Okay... that's what your code does, other than returning the result `E`. The line `V=data.size` is invalid and unnecessary, What exactly is the issue?

Comment: You're going to *have* to iterate over `data` to get the sum. There's no way around that. You could potentially do the sum whenever you're populating the map (before calling this constructor) so that you don't have to do it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for something like

```
E = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), E,
  [](size_t cur, const decltype(data)::value_type& elem) {
    return cur + elem.second.size();
  }
);
```

Not sure to what extent this is clearer than the original loop.

Comment: Of course, this just moves the loop into the STL. I'm wondering what OP's issue with `for` is.